# How to draw overlapping area graph in ggplot2 using geom_area()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw overlapping areas within ggplot. However, the following code is resulting in stacked bars:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(Status = c(rep("Close", 20),rep("Open", 30)),
                      Year = sample(c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016), 50, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, fill = Status)) + 
  geom_area(stat = 'bin', binwidth = 1)
```

The outcome will be stacked area graph.

[image]

What if I want to draw an overlapping area graph to compare each year's status?

Comment: Sorry 2nd line should be: ggplot(tryData, aes(x = Year, fill = Status)) + geom_area(stat = 'bin', binwidth = 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't understand exactly what you want but how about this?

```
tryData <- data.frame(Status = c(rep("Close", 20),
                      rep("Open", 30)),
                      Year = sample(c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016), 50, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(tryData, aes(x = Year, fill = Status)) +
  geom_area(stat = 'bin', binwidth = 1, position = "identity", alpha = .5)
```

[image]